# What should be the result type of this function?

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming

I want to write a function `saveStuff` that saves something to a file, after it passes certain tests. If tests fail, I need to raise an error. What should be the result type of this function? I thought of `IO (Either String ())` and `IO (Maybe String)`, but both of them *feel* wrong for some reason. I looked up similar functions from standard library, but they simply seem to return `IO ()`. They throw exceptions on failures. I can't find myself liking that approach.

Comment: If it can succeed in only one way, `Maybe ErrorMessage` or something isomorphic is the correct type. If you don't like `Maybe` because usually `Nothing` indicates failure, use `data Result = Success | Failure String`.

Comment: @DanielFischer: That is probably good as an answer (rather than a comment).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could consider writing something that returns an `ErrorT String IO ()`. Documentation for the `ErrorT` monad transformer is [on Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mtl/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-Error.html#t:ErrorT). There are more suggestions in the excellent [Eight Ways to Report Errors](http://www.randomhacks.net/articles/2007/03/10/haskell-8-ways-to-report-errors/) by Eric Kidd and the [follow up](http://blog.ezyang.com/2011/08/8-ways-to-report-errors-in-haskell-revisited/) some years later by Edward Yang.

Comment: `ErrorT` is what I thought of, too. You have what is essentially an `IO ()`, and you want to add the potential for an error with a message, so just slap the `ErrorT` transformer on top of it.

Answer (score 6):

If there is only one way `saveStuff` can succeed, a type isomorphic to `Maybe ErrorMessage` is the correct type. `Maybe ErrorMessage` itself has the downside that usually `Nothing` denotes failure when using `Maybe`, so it would run counter to expectations here. With regard to that, `Either ErrorMessage ()` is better, but the `()` parameter to the `Right` case doesn't carry any information, therefore that option lacks elegance too.

If you don't want to accept these shortcomings, define your own result type

```
data Result = Success | Failure ErrorMessage
-- with type ErrorMessage = String, for example
```